# Controller Support in PyGame

Tags: python, pygame

Is it possible to add a purely python code to python, more specifically in the pygame module, so that it can take direct input from a Controller (XBox One, PS4, etc.)? I have attempted to use the following code with no luck;

```
 win.onkey()
 win.use(sys())
```

Comment: Have a google of xinput if you have no luck, it's not part of pygame (I don't think) but does work great.

Comment: As an alternative to using xinput, you could also try something like pysdl2, which I assume would have an interface for the `SDL_GameController` series of functions.

Comment: Did you try the `pygame.joystick` module?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the pygame.joystick module to get button presses from any controller connected to the computer. The id you pass into pygame.joystick.Joystick(id) is the order the controller was connected to the computer, starting at 0, for most cases you can use 0.

```
import pygame

pygame.init()

window = pygame.display.set_mode((800, 600))
pygame.display.set_caption("Controller")

controller = pygame.joystick.Joystick(0)

done = False

while not done:
    if controller.get_button(0): #A
        pygame.draw.rect(window, (255, 0, 0), [0, 0, 800, 600])
    if controller.get_button(1): #B
        pygame.draw.rect(window, (0, 255, 0), [0, 0, 800, 600])
    if controller.get_button(2): #X
        pygame.draw.rect(window, (0, 0, 255), [0, 0, 800, 600])
    if controller.get_button(3): #Y
        pygame.draw.rect(window, (0, 0, 0), [0, 0, 800, 600])
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            done = True
    pygame.display.update()

pygame.quit()
```

I don't know all of the ids for the buttons, so you'll have to experiment.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to the previous answer, you don't need to experiment to find the buttons  because the pygame.joystick documentation ( https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/joystick.html ) includes mapping for various controllers.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).